# How to plot a calendar using matplotlib patches

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, graph

I would like to create a demo calendar, which reflects of the risk of a particular event happening **on each day in a month, and for each individual devices**

I came across this post online:

```
# Demo plot 
import calendar
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def plot_calendar(days, months):
    plt.figure(figsize=(9, 3))
    # non days are grayed
    ax = plt.gca().axes
    ax.add_patch(Rectangle((29, 2), width=.8, height=.8, 
                           color='gray', alpha=.3))
    ax.add_patch(Rectangle((30, 2), width=.8, height=.8,
                           color='gray', alpha=.5))
    ax.add_patch(Rectangle((31, 2), width=.8, height=.8,
                           color='gray', alpha=.5))
    ax.add_patch(Rectangle((31, 4), width=.8, height=.8,
                           color='gray', alpha=.5))
    ax.add_patch(Rectangle((31, 6), width=.8, height=.8,
                           color='gray', alpha=.5))
    ax.add_patch(Rectangle((31, 9), width=.8, height=.8,
                           color='gray', alpha=.5))
    ax.add_patch(Rectangle((31, 11), width=.8, height=.8,
                           color='gray', alpha=.5))
    for d, m in zip(days, months):
        ax.add_patch(Rectangle((d, m), 
                               width=.8, height=.8, color='C0'))
    plt.yticks(np.arange(1, 13)+.5, list(calendar.month_abbr)[1:])
    plt.xticks(np.arange(1,32)+.5, np.arange(1,32))
    plt.xlim(1, 32)
    plt.ylim(1, 13)
    plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
    # remove borders and ticks
    for spine in plt.gca().spines.values():
        spine.set_visible(False)
    plt.tick_params(top=False, bottom=False, left=False, right=False)
    plt.show()


from datetime import datetime, timedelta
def get_weekends(year):
    weekend_day = []
    weekend_month = [] 
    start = datetime(year, 1, 1)
    for i in range(365):
        day_of_the_year = start + timedelta(days=i)
        if day_of_the_year.weekday() > 4:
            weekend_day.append(day_of_the_year.day)
            weekend_month.append(day_of_the_year.month)
    return weekend_day, weekend_month
weekend_day, weekend_month = get_weekends(2018)
plot_calendar(weekend_day, weekend_month)
```

and returned a calendar below:

[image]

First, I would like to create a similar graph but instead of having Months on the `Y-axis`, I would like to have `device_1` to `device_100`, (ie. the calendar will then be for 100 devices over one month)

Second, I want to use different(or just 2) colours to represent different risk level in the grid.

Anyway, the main purpose is to create a demo calendar to visualise potential risk and I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved with the following adaptation of your code. The new function takes a parameter `days`, which should be a list of `(day, color)` tuples to mark for each device you want to plot. It also takes an optional parameter `days_in_month` to build in compatibility with months that have fewer than 31 days.

**Code:**

```
def plot_device_calendar(days, days_in_month=31):
    plt.figure(figsize=(.3*days_in_month, .3*len(days)))
    ax = plt.gca().axes
    for device, days_to_mark in enumerate(days, start=1):
        for d in days_to_mark:
            ax.add_patch(Rectangle((d[0], device), 
                                   width=.8, height=.8, color=d[1]))
    plt.yticks(np.arange(1, len(days)+1)+.5, [f"device_{i}" for i in range(1, len(days)+1)])
    plt.xticks(np.arange(1,days_in_month+1)+.5, np.arange(1,days_in_month+1))
    plt.xlim(1, days_in_month+1)
    plt.ylim(1, len(days)+1)
    plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
    for spine in plt.gca().spines.values():
        spine.set_visible(False)
    plt.tick_params(top=False, bottom=False, left=False, right=False)
    plt.show()
```

**Example Input:** (3 devices, 10 random days and colors)

```
>>> l = [[(30, 'r'), (23, 'b'), (31, 'g'), (16, 'm'), (10, 'g'), (7, 'r'), (27, 'g'), (6, 'y'), (3, 'y'), (14, 'g')],
         [(22, 'y'), (21, 'w'), (16, 'y'), (23, 'c'), (8, 'g'), (31, 'w'), (15, 'k'), (12, 'k'), (6, 'm'), (24, 'r')],
         [(31, 'c'), (10, 'c'), (2, 'k'), (17, 'g'), (30, 'y'), (3, 'g'), (14, 'y'), (23, 'y'), (4, 'r'), (22, 'r')]]
```

**Usage:**

```
>>> colors = ['b','g','r','c','m','y','k','w']
>>> l = [random.sample(range(1,32), 10) for i in range(20)]
>>> l = [[(x,random.choice(colors)) for x in sl] for sl in l]
>>> plot_device_calendar(l)
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Beautiful code and plot. I wonder if all colour could follow the same colour scheme, just to show correlation? Thanks

Comment: @nilsinelabore You can pass whatever you want as a color- either matplotlib colors: like ['r', 'b', 'g', 'c'], matplotlib color schemes: like ['C0', 'C1', ...] or even RGBA tuples: [(1,0,0,1), (0,1,0,1), (0,0,1,1), ...] see https://matplotlib.org/2.0.2/api/colors_api.html for more details.